# What is happening step by step in this C code

Tags: c

I dont understand what is happening in the code below. Please explain to me step by step

In the output Console, for the 1st printf, I get a smiley face. WHY? If i'm not mistaken, it is supposed to print the 257th ASCII, but there is no ASCII value after 255. So where is it getting the smiley face from?

Similarly for the 2nd printf i got a smiley face. WHY?

3rd printf: value is 323 as it is printing the integer value of variable d

lastly, the 4th printf: WHY does the output show 0?

```
int main()
{
    char b;
    int i = 257;
    double d = 323.142;

    b = i;
    printf("%c\n", b);

    b = (char) i;
    printf("%c\n", b);

    i = (int) d;
    printf("%d\n", i);

    b = (char) d;
    printf("%c\n", b);
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: console output]

Comment: `printf("%c\n");` makes the program have undefined behavior. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you [don’t post screenshots or photos](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: Please be more specific about _what_ you do  not understand.

Comment: Perhaps things would be clearer for you if you used `%d` and wrote `printf("%d\n", b);`, but it's not clear to me what it is that you are finding confusing.  (eg, are you confused about what is printed when you use `%c`, or are you confused about the data loss when casting to the smaller integer type, or something else enitrely.)

Comment: Regarding "it is supposed to print the 257th ASCII, but there is no ASCII value after 255": leaving aside the question of whether the execution character set is actually ASCII, what did you expect to happen when you asked the program to do something you thought was impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = i;
printf("%c\n", b);
```

This will truncate the value of `i` (257 as 4 bytes) into a one byte value (`char`), which effectively writes the result of `257 modulo 256`, ie `1`. Then it prints the character with the ASCII code `1`, which your console of choice prints as a smiley face, so it sounds like you're using the Windows console.

```
b = (char) i;
printf("%c\n", b);
```

Same as above, the cast was implied above, here it's written explicitly.

```
i = (int) d;
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Casting a floating point value (`d`) to an integer stores the integer part only, as long as it fits, otherwise it truncates it as described above. In this case it fits and you get the integer part of `323.142`, which is `323`.

```
b = (char) d;
printf("%c\n");
```

Here you didn't pass `b` to your `printf` statement, so the result is undefined. If you had, it would have printed character `323 modulo 256` which is `67`, which is a `C`.

As an aside, I find hilarious the amount of people "answering" you in comments that they're confused. If this confused me, I wouldn't be so quick to announce it to the world.

Comment: "*This will truncate the value of `i`*" -- maybe.  Probably, even.  But if `char` is a signed type (which is common) then the type conversion that occurs when assigning an out-of-range value of type `int` to a variable of type `char` produces implementation defined behavior or generates an implementation-defined signal.  The C language specification does not by any means guarantee truncation behavior such as you describe.  Same for an explicit conversion by typecast.  Same for conversion of an out-of range FP value to type `int` or (if it is signed) `char`.

Comment: I believe `b = (char) d;` is undefined behavior because the integer part of `d` can't be represented as a char. It's 6.3.1.4.1 in the C99 standard "When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool,
the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of
the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined." Maybe sometimes it's better to be confused...

Comment: Permissive specifications are nice because they allow implementations to optimize for platform-specific quirks, rather than be forced to follow the letter of the specification. The downside, of course, is when the people in a position to help new-comers to learn instead hide under their desks at the sight of an obviously trivial cast and scream for repentance. Downvote away if you wish, Paul and John (oh hey, Biblical names, how fitting for my analogy), but what I described above is how every system the OP will ever touch in his life will behave, period.

Comment: Re “what I described above is how every system the OP will ever touch in his life will behave, period“: No, it is not. In this simple case, the numbers may work out that way, especially since the compiler can see all the values and perform the calculations at compile-time. But a floating-point-to-integer conversion is likely to be implemented with a machine instruction that produces some “default” result for out-of-range results, and then the result of converting a floating-point value to a `char` will not be the source value modulo 256 but will be the default result.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts guys. Yes I'm just learning coding so I might have some very noobish questions. i'm sure this is the place to ask and get help regarding these problems though. some fo your explanations have been more helpful than any text book.

I did have an idea as to what was happening here, like it was showing ASCII characters but I wasn't able to understand how the conversion was happening.

Something that im still not understanding is why 256? 1 byte = 11111111 = 255.
So why do we have to Modulo with 256 to find the remainder?

Answer (score 0):

> `b = i;`
> `printf("%c\n", b);`

When an `int` is assigned to a `char`:

- If `char` is unsigned, the value is wrapped modulo `CHAR_MAX`+1, commonly 256. This maps 257 to 1.
- If `char` is signed, the conversion produces a value or signal defined by the C implementation. Wrapping modulo 256 is common.

Printing the value 1 with `%c` prints the character with code 1, which is apparently a smiley face in the C implementation you are using. (This is not ASCII; ASCII does not have smiley faces, although other characters in the character set may be ASCII.)

(The C standard allows the `char` type to be signed or unsigned. It is up to each implementation to define which.)

> `b = (char) i;`
> `printf("%c\n", b);`

This performs the same conversion and printing above. Using `(char)` just makes the conversion explicit.

> `i = (int) d;`
> `printf("%d\n", i);`

When a `double` is converted to `int`, the fractional part is discarded. If the integer part can fit in an `int`, that is the result. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. For converting `323.142`, 323 fits in an `int`, so that is the result, and that is what is printed for `i`.

> `b = (char) d;`
> `printf("%c\n", b);`

Converting a `double` to a `char` is similar; if the integer part cannot fit, the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. Since 323 will not fit into a `char`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. Below are some examples of behavior observed in this case.

Using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char b;
    double d = 323.142;

    b = (char) d;
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eGcG457sb) shows, for GCC 12.2 with `-O0` output of “67”.

Changing `-O0` to `-O3` produces output of “127”.

Clang 15.0.0 with `-O0` also produces “67”.

Clang 15.0.0 with `-O3` produces “1360786488”. Observe it is not possible for a `char` to have a value of 1,360,786,488 in this C implementation, so the conversion has not merely produced a value for the `char`; it has “broken” the behavior of the program more drastically.